# .disabled doesn't work multiple variables

Tags: swiftui

I have the code below:

```
struct ContentView: View {
@State var ex1 = "ABC"
@State var ex2 = "ABC"
@State var ex3 = "123"

var body: some View {
Button(action: {
  ex1 = "cba" //This makes the button not disabled anymore
}) {
 Text("toggle button not disabled")
}

Button(action: {
  ex3 = "321" //this does nothing
}) {
 Text("Changing this does nothing")
}
Button(action: {
  ex3 = "123" //this does nothing
}) {
 Text("this puts ex3 back to original")
}


Button(action: {
   //actions
}) {
  Text("Test button")
}
.disabled(ex1 == ex2 || ex3 == "123")
}
}
```

The problem is; As soon as ex1 doesn't equal ex2, the button enables. Even if ex3 still equals `123`.

-Pressing the top button fulfills the first condition
-pressing the middle button fulfills the second condition

that should make the button able to get clicked, but the second condition doesn't do anything. All that has to work is condition 1.

Comment: Not reproducible

Comment: @Iorem ipsum updated

Comment: Why are you using lowercase for `button` and `view`. This doesn’t compile.

Comment: I fixed this. Now it should compile!